# How to add store name on all pages?

Tags: opencart, title, opencart-3

In opencart 3.0.2.0 How do I add my store’s name to all pages (product, manufacturer, information etc)?

Thank You

Comment: Where do you want to show it? header? footer? content?

Comment: @DigitCart Store Name In Page Title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to edit your page title to something like this:
*Your Store - Product Name*

**Edit this file:**

```
catalog\controller\product\product.php
```

**Find:**

```
$this->document->setTitle($product_info['meta_title']);
```

**Replace With:**

```
$this->document->setTitle($this->config->get('config_name') . ' - ' . $product_info['meta_title']);
```

You can do the same for other pages like `category.php`, you need to search for `setTitle`.

Answer (score 0):

`$this->config->get('config_name')` - name of store